# how to group by date and unique each group and count each group with pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

how to group by date and unique each group and count each group with pandas?

Count number of unique MAC address each day

```
pd.concat([df[['date','Client MAC']], df8[['date',"MAC address"]].rename(columns={"MAC address":"Client MAC"})]).groupby(["date"])


one of column , data example
Association Time
Mon May 14 19:41:20 HKT 2018
Mon May 14 19:43:22 HKT 2018
Tue May 15 09:24:57 HKT 2018
Mon May 14 19:53:33 HKT 2018
```

i use

```
starttime=datetime.datetime.now()
dff4 = (df4[['Association Time','Client MAC Address']].groupby(pd.to_datetime(df4["Association Time"]).dt.date.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))).nunique())
print datetime.datetime.now()-starttime
```

it runs for 2 minutes, but it also group by association time, it is wrong,
not need to group by association time

```
                  Association Time  Client MAC Address
Association Time
2017-06-21                       1                   3
2018-02-21                       2                   8
2018-02-27                       1                   1
2018-03-07                       3                   3
```

Comment: Is possible add some data sample? Only 5 rows is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need add `['Client MAC'].nunique()`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df[['date','Client MAC']], 
           df8[['date',"MAC address"]].rename(columns={"MAC address":"Client MAC"})])
        .groupby(["date"])['Client MAC']
        .nunique())
```

If `date`s are datetimes:

```
df = (pd.concat([df[['date','Client MAC']], 
                df8[['date',"MAC address"]].rename(columns={"MAC address":"Client MAC"})]))

df = df['Client MAC'].groupby(df["date"].dt.date).nunique()
```

Comment: how about date is this format Mon May 14 19:41:20 HKT 2018  ?  i use dff4 = (df4[['Association Time','Client MAC Address']].groupby(pd.to_datetime(df4["Association Time"]).dt.date.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))).nunique())    run a very long time

Comment: @MartinLee - i think need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S HKT %Y')`, tested with `df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['Mon May 14 19:41:20 HKT 2018','Mon May 14 19:41:20 HKT 2019']})`